# How to show that if $\gamma \alpha=0$ (mod $A$) then $\alpha = 0$ (mod $A$)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $A$ be an ideal of $\mathcal O$ (Ring of integers of some algeibraic number field) and assume that $gcd([\gamma],A)= [1]$. How to show that if $\gamma \alpha=0$ (mod $A$) then $\alpha = 0$ (mod $A$). I know that the assumption $gcd([\gamma],A)= [1]$ means that $[\gamma]+A= \mathcal O$ and that $\gamma \alpha = 0$ (mod $A$) means that $\gamma \alpha \in A$. So the question now becomas: Show that if $[\gamma]+A= \mathcal O$ and $\gamma \alpha \in A$ then $\alpha \in A$.

I'm pretty new to ideals and everything I try doesn't make sense really.

Another little question: When we define that $A|B$ means that $AC=B$ for some ideals $A,B,C$ and $a = b$ (mod $A$) s.t. $a-b \in A$. Can we say that $a=b$ (mod $A$) also means that $A|a-b$ and then $AC=a-b$ for some ideal C?

Comment: What does $\mod A$ mean? Everything is equal mod the ideal $(1)$..

Comment: @AlexYoucis $A$ is an ideal. IF $a = b$ (mod $A$) then $a-b \in A$.

Comment: Let me know if that's helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\gamma\alpha=0\mod A$. Then, $\gamma\alpha\in A$, or, said differently, $(\gamma)(\alpha)\subseteq A$. But, this is equivalent to $A\mid (\gamma)(\alpha)$. But, since $((\gamma),A)=1$ this implies that $A\mid(\alpha)$ and so $(\alpha)\subseteq A$. But, this is equivalent to $\alpha\equiv 0\mod A$.

Comment: Indeed that's helpful! Didnt realise that if $(\alpha) \subseteq A$ then $\alpha \in A$. Sure its trivial but just didn't see it.

Comment: @Kplusn Glad to help. :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis How does it follow that if $A|(\gamma)(\alpha)$ and $((\gamma),A)=(1)$ then $A|(\alpha)$? With numbers sure its trivial but with ideals cant see it right away.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen Just by applying unique factorization of ideals in a Dedekind domain.

Comment: @AlexYoucis   I think I haven't heard of that one yet.